# Looping through DOM with jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I had an idea for Wordpress dynamically choose the smallest featured image for responsive design. I've just two sizes. In html the one with extension "-360x360" is coded. The large one ends just .jpg. The idea is just to strip the extension off when the parent  is larger. For now simply inline code.

I get the right width of . Also getting in the loop. But the DOM doesn't change.
And I really thought it was working last night... ;)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var width = $("article").width();
//alert (width);
if ( width > 360 ) {
//alert("in loop");
  $("article").children("img").each(function( index, element ) {
    $( element ).attr( "width", "720" );
    $( element ).attr( "height", "720" );
    var src = $( element ).attr("src");
    var index = $( element ).attr("src").indexOf("-360x360");
    var new_src = src.substring(0,index) + ".jpg";
    $( element ).attr( "src", new_src );
    });
  };
});
</script>
```

Comment: You'll have to change that DOM ready function if you're working with Wordpress. Do `jQuery(function($) { ... code here ... });` instead.

Comment: Are you getting an error of something like $ is undefined? IF so, listen to adeneo, if not, please post any errors that appear in the console or provide a link to a jsfiddle or live example

Comment: I changed to `jQuery(function($) {` adeneo but no difference. I do not get any errors :) but when I add `alert( $( element ).attr("src"));` in the each loop it seems like nothing is found?